# Div overlaps another div

Tags: html, css

My layout is supposed to unfold the three images when I press the switch, but at the moment it slips out completely and I can't find the error at all.

[image: This the Picture from the site]

The Body the big div that encloses everything.

I know this is a lot of of code, but I think it is necessary to see everything that is included. I've played around with float and positions, but so far nothing has really worked and it's still been kicked out.
If necessary, I can also provide the entire file as a zip, which then only needs to be used on Xampp or similar, as the document also contains a lot of PHP.

If anyone knows where exactly the problem lies, I would be very grateful, because at the moment I don't really know.

```css
body.hg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#00aaff, #ffa64d);
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Hauptdivcontainer */

div.haupt {
  background: #F8FCFF;
  max-width: 1000px;
  mix-height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 30px 0px #000000;
}

div.jtzt {
  background: #D8F0FF;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px thin #290A0A;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px #1E1E1E;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

h3.bewirb {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000939;
}


/* Switcher */

.containerino {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.switcher {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.switcher input {
  display: none;
}

.sliderding {
  background-color: #9B2022;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.sliderding:before {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 4px;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 26px;
}

input:checked+.sliderding {
  background-color: #66bb6a;
}

input:checked+.sliderding:before {
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.sliderding.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.sliderding.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div.uploaddiv {
  position: inherit;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  float: inherit;
  left: 90%;
}


/* Uploaddinger */

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 8px 10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.upload {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #666;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.upload-icon {
  margin: 25px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.upload-input {
  position: relative;
  top: -62px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 hotpink;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 deeppink;
}


/* default-Zustand */


/* bei gesetztem Haken wird der Inhalt eingeblendet */

input.checkbox:checked~div.uploaddiv {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="jtzt">
  <h3 class="bewirb">Bewirb dich jetzt!</h3>
  <div class="containerino">s
    <label class="switcher" for="checkbox">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
        <div class="sliderding round"></div>
    
        
            <div class="uploaddiv">   
                
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
                    </div>

                        <div class="dropzone">
                              <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
                              <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Anschreiben</button>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
                    </div>

                        <div class="dropzone">
                              <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
                              <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Lebenslauf</button>
                </div> 
                    
                
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
                    </div>

                        <div class="dropzone">
                              <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
                              <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
                        </div>

                        <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Zeugnisse</button>
                </div>
           </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly, your `html` is probably wrong. Your `div.uploaddiv` is inside your `label.switcher`, doesn't look good to me. You also have incorrect css properties, like `mix-height`.

Comment: If I close the label directly after the label it works, but then the style of the button is gone. I am still a beginner in HTML, how can I solve this best?

Answer (score 0):

It works now.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #8B0000;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 450px;
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 90px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input:checked+label {
  background: #bada55;
}

input:checked+label:after {
  left: calc(100% - 2px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: #fff;
}

div.uploaddiv {
  position: inherit;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jtzt">
  <h3 class="bewirb">Bewirb dich jetzt!</h3>

  <input type="checkbox" id="switch" style="padding-left: 10000px" />
  <label for="switch">Toggle</label>

  <div class="uploaddiv">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="dropzone">
        <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
        <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Anschreiben</button>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="dropzone">
        <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
        <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Lebenslauf</button>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="upload">Drop file to upload</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="dropzone">
        <img src="http://100dayscss.com/codepen/upload.svg" class="upload-icon" />
        <input type="file" class="upload-input" />
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn" name="uploadbutton">Zeugnisse</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. It's not at all clear what you changed. Please see [answer], and don't forget to accept the answer.